# Javascript: In promises what is the purpose of resolve and reject?

Tags: javascript, promise

As I understand it, resolve and reject are specified in the callback provided to the promise constructor and invoked within the callback. But resolve and reject (I think) always do the same thing, so why do they even have to be specified?

EDIT: I should clarify: I do not think that resolve does the same thing as reject; I mean resolve seems to always resolve and reject always reject -- is there a way to pass in a function instead of resolve that does something else?

EDIT: To further clarify as I did in a comment below: if a Promise constructor takes a function which in turn takes resolve and reject and these are always to be called in the function, why must resolve and reject be specified as arguments at all?

**Final Edit:** I tried with foo instead of resolve and it still worked. How can that be? I did not define foo at all?? I probably am not understanding something about javascript beyond promises. [code snippet where i changed resolve to foo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: They don't do the same thing. What gave you that idea?

Comment: What do you mean by “always do the same thing”? What do you think they do? How would you resolve a Promise without `resolve` available?

Comment: If you do not specify them, how would you call them when the promise is done or has an error?

Comment: `reject(…)` could have been replaced by `resolve(Promise.reject(…))`, sure, but no they don't do the same thing? And even you needed only one - why do you think that one wouldn't need to be specified?

Comment: By "specified", do you mean "declared as a parameter"?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a JS Promise, you expect some task to happen asynchronously. It is possible, that this task can succeed or fail. The success and failure are defined based on what the task is.

When you create a new Promise, you as the creator must specify what to do when the task is successful or is a failure. To communicate the same to the consumer of the promise resolve/reject come handy.

So when the consumer uses a `then` to check the output of the promise. what ever is returned by resolve is given to the consumer.

When the consumer uses a `catch` to check the output of the promise. whatever is returned by the reject is given to the consumer.

```
import {Promise} from 'es6-promise'


const foo = true;
const bar = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (foo) {
        resolve(4);
    } else {
        reject(2);
    }
})
bar.then((value) => console.log(value)).catch((value) => console.log(value));
```

you can run the above sample by changing the value of foo to true/false and see for yourself what the output is.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a ton of time trying to figure this out. Unfortunately, for anyone well versed with JS syntax, won't really understand the question...

For me, it was clear, after unraveling the concise JS syntactic sugar:

```
function promise_executor(resolve_callback_provided_by_promise_instance, reject_callback_provided_by_promise_instance) {
    if (<some_condition>) {
        // success
        var response='bla';
        resolve_callback_provided_by_promise_instance(response);
    } else {
        // fail
        var error=new Error('failed');
        reject_callback_provided_by_promise_instance(error);
    }
}

var promise_instance = new Promise(promise_executor);
```

So the `reject` and `resolve` are just random names for callbacks that the promise instance will call.

They have proper interfaces, like both will take 1 param of type object. That param will be passed to either the Promise.then() or the Promise.catch().

[resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

[reject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)

---

Then, when you use them, it is like this:

```
function success_callback(param_from_resolve) {
    console.log('success() ', param_from_resolve);
}

function fail_callback(param_from_reject) {
    console.log('fail(): ', param_from_reject);
}

promise_instance
.then(success_callback)   // this will be the var 'resolve' from above
.catch(fail_callback);    // this will be the var 'error' from above
```

The whole code flow is like this:

<at some point, your `promise_executor()` code is called with 2 functions, as parameters>

```
// obviously, the promise_executor() function has its own name in the Promise object
promise_executor(Promise.reject, Promise.resolve);
```

<`promise_executor()` will -hopefully- call either the resolve or the reject callback, which will in turn trigger either the callback of `then()` or `catch()`>

<say we have `then()`>

<the Promise code will take the `response` param from `resolve_callback_provided_by_promise_instance(response)` and give it to the callback from `then()`>

```
param_from_resolve(response)
```

---

It will go down something like this (THIS IS NOT what actually happens, as in reality, the micro-queue, the eventloop, etc. gets involved - this is a linearized version of the gist of what is happening):

**What you see:**

```
var promise = new Promise(promise_executor);
```

***What is executed:***

```
function Promise.constructor(exec_callback_fnc) {
    var this = object();
    this.exec_callback_fnc = exec_callback_fnc; // this is "promise_executor"
    return this;
}
```

**What you see:**

```
// at some point in "this.exec_callback_fnc":
resolve_callback_provided_by_promise_instance(response)
```

***What is executed:***

```
function promise_instance.resolve(param) {
    this.param_from_resolve = param;
    promise_instance.resolved = true;
}
```

**What you see:**

```
promise_instance
.then(success_callback)
```

***What is executed:***

```
promise_instance.exec_callback_fnc(promise_instance.resolve, promise_instance.reject);

if (promise_instance.resolved) {

    function promise_instance.then(callback_fnc) {
        callback_fnc(this.param_from_resolve);  // this is "success_callback"
    }
}
```

---

Finally, let's see, how the syntax makes this whole thing more concise:

```
function promise_executor(resolve_callback_provided_by_promise_instance,
                          reject_callback_provided_by_promise_instance) {
    if (<some_condition>) {
        // success
        var response='bla';
        resolve_callback_provided_by_promise_instance(response);
    } else {
        // fail
        var error=new Error('failed');
        reject_callback_provided_by_promise_instance(error);
    }
}

var promise_instance = new Promise(promise_executor);

function success_callback(param_from_resolve) {
    console.log('success() ', param_from_resolve);
}

function fail_callback(param_from_reject) {
    console.log('fail(): ', param_from_reject);
}

promise_instance
.then(success_callback)
.catch(fail_callback);
```

Will become:

```
new Promise((resolve_callback_provided_by_promise_instance,
             reject_callback_provided_by_promise_instance) => {
    if (<some_condition>) {
        // success
        var response='bla';
        resolve_callback_provided_by_promise_instance(response);
    } else {
        // fail
        var error=new Error('failed');
        reject_callback_provided_by_promise_instance(error);
    }})
// "response" -> "param_from_resolve"
.then((param_from_resolve) => { console.log('success() ', param_from_resolve); })
 // "error" -> "param_from_reject"
.catch((param_from_reject) => { console.log('fail(): ', param_from_reject); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the `then()` function which takes two callbacks, one when the promise is resolved and one when it is resolved. The pattern often looks like this:

```
myPromise.then(result => {
        // do something here
    },
    error => {
    }
);
```

If the promise is resolved everything went as expected and the first callback should proceed as normal. If the promise is rejected the second callback  should perform error handling, possibly displaying an appropriate message to the user. These never do the same thing.

If you have logic that should always occur, whether there is an error or not, you should chain another call to `then()`:

```
myPromise.then(result => {
        // do something here
    },
    error => {
        // do something here
    }
).then(result => {
        // do something here
    }
);
```

This is conceptually the same as `try...catch...finally` from many programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve and reject do not "do the same thing".

When you resolve a promise you are saying "this is the successful response of this promise".

When you reject a promise you are saying "this promise failed because...".

For example:

Imagine in the following examples `accountApiRequest()` actually does an API request to fetch an account. If there is no account it will most likely return `null` or throw an exception.

When a promise is successful you will `resolve` it. When a promise is not successful it will be `rejected`.

## Successful promise

```js
function accountApiRequest() {
    return {
        id: 1234,
        username: 'Jim',
    }
}

function getAccount() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        account = accountApiRequest()
        if (!account) {
            return reject('Unable to fetch account')
        }
        return resolve(account)
    });
}

getAccount().then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

## Failed promise

```js
function accountApiRequest() {
    return null
}

function getAccount() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        account = accountApiRequest()
        if (!account) {
            return reject('Unable to fetch account')
        }
        return resolve(account)
    });
}

getAccount().then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

Comment: My question is, where is the implied type for resolve determined? I mean, in Java, the resolve parameter would be a type/class. How is resolve's behavior determined?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `resolve` is just a callback function, more specifically you can imagine that `resolve` is `console.log` in this case. You can call them whatever you want but it is the order of parameters in the `Promise` constructor that determine what they are used for.

Answer (score 0):

In the Promise constructor we have a callback which takes the `resolve` and `reject` methods as its arguments. After a Promise is created using the constructor a Promise can have three states:

1. Pending
2. Resolved
3. Rejected

When a promise is resolved then the callback which is passed in the `then()` method is called. If the promise is rejected the callback which is passed in the `catch()` method is called. For example:

```js
const prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
      resolve('resolved');
    } else {
      reject('rejected');
    }
  }
  , 2000)
  
});

prom.then((val) => console.log('succes: ' + val))
    .catch((val) => console.log('fail: ' + val))
```

In our example the resolve or reject is called in a `setTimeout`, therefore the status of the promise is the first 2 seconds **pending**. After the `setTimeout` is expired the Promise is either resolved or rejected based on the value of `Math.random()`. Then either the `then` or the `catch` callback is executed to handle the result of the promise.

- When the promise is rejected the callback passed in the `catch` method is called
- When the promise is resolved the callback passed in the `then` method is called

Comment: If instead of "Promise((resolve, reject) =>..." could we say "Promise((foo,bar)=>..." and define foo and bar functions? If not, if resolve and reject must always be used and they always have the same functionality, why must they be specified at all?

Comment: The names are irrelevant, you could use Promise((foo,bar)=>.. like you said. In the promise Constructor these are just function exposed as arguments by the function which is passed in the Promise constructor. This is just the way this API works.

Comment: new Promise always takes a function and exposes 2 arguments (res, rej) which are functions, you don't have to  use them, but you can. The names are arbitrary but they let you easily resolve or reject a promise based on your own predefined conditions.

Comment: If I indeed use foo and bar, do those functions have to be defined? When I type in "resolve" or "Resolve()" or "Resolve" at a node prompt, I get back "is not defined" which surprised me -- I would have thought Resolve is a built-in function like Promise is. This is sort of the essence of my confusion, I think.

Comment: If I use "foo" as the first argument to "resolve" the promise, will "foo" be understood to be something that resolves or would it have to be predefined? If so, where is "resolve" defined?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question when I read about Promises. And I came to understanding that you don't need to define resolve and reject functions by yourself (they will be ignored and standard resolve/reject functions will be called anyway): I think of them as special functions which let you indicate whether to resolve or reject the promise by calling one of them; and what value to return in each case by passing arguments to these functions. It doesn't matter how you name them in promise constructor - first argument is resolve function and the second - reject.